# Bash calculate days in two date

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash. I have a command to calculate the days between given date and current date.

This one is working (The given date is a sring):

`daysToExpiry=$((($(date +%s --date "Oct 15 05:17:34 2023 GMT")-$(date +%s))/(3600*24)))`

But, I got error "date: extra operand ‘15’" with this command (the same date string in a variable):

`daysToExpiry=$((($(date +%s --date $expiry)-$(date +%s))/(3600*24)))`

`$expiry` is "Oct 15 05:17:34 2023 GMT". I am wondering what's wrong with the using variable `$expiry`?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing wrong with the variable, not quoting it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out, I should use `"$expiry"`